# JSONException to parse HTML formatted text

Tags: android, android-studio, android-json, jsonexception

I'm calling a web service from my Android application. The web service returns the following JSON :
[image: JSON Image]

Now the problem is when I'm trying to get the description element of the record object I'm getting an exception as `org.json.JSONException: No value for description`

Now my question is **how can I get the value of the description using the existing parser without changing the response JSON format**.

Comment: Share your code, how are you getting the description from JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to me,

**You are using the wrong object to get description value** otherwise `org.json.JSONException: No value for description` error will not occur.

Also, check if you can using  `optString` instead of `getString` which just returns null if value do not exist, instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: Yes, you're correct, it's a mistake from my end. I was trying to read from the wrong object.